# Custom scorer with third parameter in grid search

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I need to make a scorer that calculates a score based on three lists/arrays `y_true`, `y_pred`, and `sample_value`. The problem is that the scorer inside grid search calculates a score both for training and validation set and I don't know how to distinguish it. This is how I tried to do (full example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

def RF_metric(y_true, y_pred, sample_value):

    dict_temp = {'y_pred': list(y_pred), 'y_true': list(y_true),
                 'sample_value': sample_value}
    
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(dict_temp)
    df_temp['daily_score'] = df_temp[['y_pred', 'y_true', 'sample_value']].apply(
        lambda row: row[2] if row[0] == row[1] else -row[2], axis=1)

    df_temp['cum_score'] = df_temp['daily_score'].cumsum()
    final_score = df_temp['cum_score'].to_list()[-1]

    return final_score

param_dict = {'n_estimators': [100, 150, 200],
                  'max_depth': [5, 10, 15],
                  }

dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-10-01')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'A':np.random.rand(len(dates)), 'B':np.random.rand(len(dates)),
                   'label':np.random.choice([0,1],len(dates)), 'sample_value':np.random.rand(len(dates))})

train_start = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
train_end = pd.to_datetime('2020-06-01')
val_start = train_end
val_end = pd.to_datetime('2020-07-01')

df_train = df[(train_start <= df['Date']) & (df['Date'] < train_end)]
df_val = df[(val_start <= df['Date']) & (df['Date'] < val_end)]

cv_list = [(list(df_train.index), list(df_val.index))]
X = df[['A', 'B']].values
Y = df[['label']].values.ravel()

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
scoring = make_scorer(RF_metric, sample_value = df_val['sample_value'].to_list())

gs = GridSearchCV(clf, param_dict, cv=cv_list, scoring=scoring,n_jobs=4)
gs.fit(X,Y)
```

and the error is `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: Your example code runs fine for me, in both sklearn 0.22.2.post1 and 0.24.0.

Comment: Had version 0.20.3 and after updating to 0.23.2. it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since upgrading your version helped, it seems the problem is that `return_train_score` used to default to `True`, so indeed your `scoring` was passed the training set but with the validation's `sample_value`.

One solution (that would help e.g. if you did still want the training score, or wanted to switch to a kfold cross-validation) is to not use the convenience function `make_scorer`.  It just returns a callable with signature `(estimator, X, y)` where larger "score" is better.  You can just write your own such callable, and then you have access to all of `X` (including the column `sample_value`!) instead of just the estimator's predictions.

Comment: Can you explain more of provid a code snippet for returning the training score?

Comment: Ah, good call, I don't think the half-idea I had in mind will work, because `X` should _not_ contain the sample values (lest they be used as a feature in the model).